# Insert not inserting in property

Tags: c#, string, properties, insert

Insert not adding to variable in property

```
private string _DirectoryList = "";
public string DirectoryListAdd
        {
            get { return _DirectoryList; }
            set
            {
                    _DirectoryList.Insert(0, value + Environment.NewLine);
                    OnPropertyChanged("DirectoryListAdd");
            }
        }

public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DirectoryListAdd = "a";
            DirectoryListAdd = "b";
            Console.WriteLine(DirectoryListAdd);
        }
```

This is returning "". I wouldve expected it to return

```
a
b
```

Comment: Don't use properties that way. Assignment should mean assignment. Also, `String` is *immutable*. `String.Insert()` returns a new string, which you're discarding. It's very difficult for me to imagine what prevented you from reading the documentation on the method you're calling.

Comment: While the last part of the first comment could have been phrased differently, there does come some frustration with questions that could easily be resolved by the user just pressing `F1` on the method name that's not functioning "how they expect", since the expectation of functionality should be based at least in part on the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx

> Returns a new string in which a specified string is inserted at a specified index position in this instance.

```
_DirectoryList = _DirectoryList.Insert(0, value + Environment.NewLine);
```

+1 for "Don't use properties that way"

Answer (score 0):

```
  private string _DirectoryList = "";
  public string DirectoryListAdd
    {
        get { return _DirectoryList; }
        set
        {
                _DirectoryList=_DirectoryList.Insert(0, value + Environment.NewLine);
                OnPropertyChanged("DirectoryListAdd");
        }
    }

  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DirectoryListAdd = "a";
        DirectoryListAdd = "b";
        Console.WriteLine(DirectoryListAdd);
    }
```

note the `_DirectoryList=_DirectoryList.Insert(0, value + Environment.NewLine);`

This method would Insert at the begninng of the string not at the end like you want it to. So keep that in mind. replace the 0 `_DirectoryList.Length-1`

also as other comments say, dont use properties this way. It's more confusing than it's worth